# MediaBrowserService and MediaStore

Tags: android, mediabrowserservice

How to use [MediaBrowserService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/media/MediaBrowserService.html) to load media from different providers(Files Explorer, GoogleDrive, ContentProvider, etc) keeping single service

Checked with UAMP, its only uses one provider

My second question is what is the purpose of [onLoadItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/media/MediaBrowserService.html#onLoadItem(java.lang.String,%20android.service.media.MediaBrowserService.Result%3Candroid.media.browse.MediaBrowser.MediaItem%3E))

Comment: your question is a bit too broad. Have you attempted to do this? What have you tried? Are you running into a specific problem? Do you have any code that you've been working with? Please post it if so. These are typically what's required to help with these types of questions.

Comment: Also, when you say "what is the purpose of onLoadItem?" What exactly are you looking for? The docs clearly state what the purpose is but without more information on what you're asking, I'm not going to be able to be very helpful.

Comment: Question Cleary state my problem, second question is in which scenario onLOadItem is called?

Comment: Let's see if anyone gives you an answer ;-)